# GJS Synchronous GET http request

Tags: httprequest, synchronous, gjs

I have tried and searched but I haven't found any example or explanation on how to make a synchronous GET request to get a JSON for example. Only thing I found was ONE simple code for async request using SOUP, which actually worked, but it was async so of no use to me :/
I think SOUP can be used to make a synchornous request, but the way the gjs documentation works didn't help me to find out how.
So I figured, sure someone must know how to do this, he/she just didn't post it anywhere. Therefore I'm asking. Please, how do I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, I have found a libsoup documentation for C that is actually usable, and used google site: search argument to find the GJS wrappers. And I made it work :)
Here is the example code I made, how I wanted. Hope it works for you too :)

```
const Soup = imports.gi.Soup;

let sessionSync = new Soup.SessionSync();

let msg = Soup.Message.new('GET', 'https://www.example.com/json?arg=something');

sessionSync.send_message(msg);

print(msg.response_body.data);
```